# Is there a legacy toolchain for Android NDK r9c?

Tags: android-ndk

Trying to use VS-Android with the latest NDK but it doesn't include the old toolchain. 
[The site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) says *With NDK revision 9 and higher, the release packages have been split to reduce download size. The first download for each platform contains the default NDK toolchain. The second download contains legacy NDK toolchains for that platform*
But there is only one package for every platform. I can't find a way to get older versions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[android-ndk-r9b-windows-x86-legacy-toolchains.zip](http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r9b-windows-x86-legacy-toolchains.zip)